# using vcpkg to download dependencies without create dll

Tags: c++, windows, vcpkg

I am using `vcpkg` to download `cpprest` package, So i can use `cpprest` in my project:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
```

But after build my project, it will generate executable binary and also generate `cpprest.dll`, `LIBEAY32.dll` and `SSLEAY32.dll` and `zlib1.dll` in the Release folder

How to combile the dll into one executable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use static libraries in such cases and the command line will go like so . No DLL files will be required as the lib libraries can be linked directly to produce executables.

```
  .\vcpkg install ccprest:x64-windows-static
```

Comment: should i remove the cpprest before?

Comment: No. The static libraries will be built separately.

Comment: is it also nesscerry config Visual Studio to using static linraries?

Comment: Should I change Code Generation -> Runtime Library to Multi-Threaded(/MT)?

Comment: @TangMonk: Yes, it should work in both release and debug versions. You can mannually link or use .\vcpkg integrate install , so that the libraries are ready for your project.